# Crontab job does not work properly

Tags: perl, cron

I have to schedule a crontab job for my Perl script. To have proper environment variables I execute it via Bash script. It is executing properly, but not able to execute a GFS command which is:

```
my $string = `gluster file info`;
```

My cron job is: (calling it through a Bash script)

```
* * * * * /root/MyWeb-App/bin/crontab.pl PATH=/MyWeb-App/bin
```

My Bash script is:

```
#!/bin/bash    
/root/MyWeb-App/bin/crontab.pl
```

After executing the script, `$string` is empty. So what's wrong with this?

Comment: What error did you get?

Answer (score 2):

Right now, you are passing `PATH=/MyWeb-App/bin` as an argument to `crontab.pl`. I doubt that `crontab.pl` even check for arguments.

Perhaps you were trying to set the `PATH` environment variable. If so, the syntax is:

```
PATH=/MyWeb-App/bin /root/MyWeb-App/bin/crontab.pl
```

You might want to add to `$PATH` rather than replacing it, though.

```
PATH="/MyWeb-App/bin:$PATH" /root/MyWeb-App/bin/crontab.pl
```

Comment: Thanks for your rply...but my script is executing...i am getting output to my targeted file but it is not able to get output of command `gluster file info` that why it would not give proper output.... so why not executing that command.....if you want i will post my code here........

Comment: I know your script is executing, but `gluster` isn't. (Well, you're not clear on that. You say `$script` is empty, but that's impossible. Do you mean it's undef, or it's an empty string?) If my answer doesn't help, tell us what error you are getting. Backticks reports errors via `$?`. If a shell ends up being launched, it will additionally output errors to STDERR.

Comment: This is my code  
`my $string = `gluster volume info`;  
my $var = $?;  
print "zzz:$string\n";  
print "xxx:$var\n\n";`  
when run directly: $var = 0...    when run via crontab: $var = -1

Comment: -1 means the error is in `$!`. I bet it's permission denied or file not found.

Comment: yes it gives error:  No such file or directory
why it is and what is the solution

Comment: Specify the full path to `gluster`, or add it to PATH as I showed in my answer.